# Application-defined or object-defined error VBA Copy between Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have just started working on VBA, and I'm stuck with this error while copying data between different sheets.

The requirement was to find specific block of data points and copy them on a separate sheet.

Variable like `FirstRowArrayCol1` Contain the position of Data points, whereas `i` denotes the column numbeer.

The error is coming in this line

```
Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Cells(i, firstPos))
```

Please check the below code. Greatly Appreciate any help, thanks.

```
Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each firstPos In FirstRowArrayCol1
            If firstPos = 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            For Each secondPos In SecondRowArrayCol1
                If secondPos = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                Diff = Abs(firstPos - secondPos)
                If Diff > 0 And Diff <= 5 Then
                    Debug.Print (column3 & firstPos & "," & column3 & secondPos & "," & column4 & firstPos & "," & column4 & secondPos)
                    'Copy Data
                    Set rngSource = wksSource.Range(Cells(i, firstPos), Cells(i + 1, secondPos))
                    rngSource.Range(Cells(i, firstPos), Cells(i + 1, secondPos)).Select
                    rngSource.Copy
                    'Paste Data Values
                    Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Cells(i, firstPos))
                    rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

                End If
            Next secondPos
            For Each secondPos In SecondRowArrayCol2
                If secondPos = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                Diff = Abs(firstPos - secondPos)
                If Diff > 0 And Diff <= 5 Then
                    Debug.Print (column3 & firstPos & "," & column3 & secondPos & "," & column4 & firstPos & "," & column4 & secondPos)
                    'Copy Data
                    Set rngSource = wksSource.Range(Cells(i, firstPos), Cells(i + 1, secondPos))
                    rngSource.Range(Cells(i, firstPos), Cells(i + 1, secondPos)).Select
                    rngSource.Copy
                    'Paste Data Values
                    Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Cells(i, firstPos))
                    rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

                End If
            Next secondPos
        Next firstPos
```

Comment: FirstRowArrayCol1 etc are these ranges?

Comment: @QHarr .. was just typing that :)

Comment: They are storing row numbers as arrays specifically

Comment: So they are variants?

Comment: No they are stored in Integer arrays

Comment: I think you have your answer below but as a side note: I wouldn't use array in this instance as your are working directly with the range anyway. So would suggest to use the `Range`

Comment: Thanks... Will fix it up... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Worksheet.Range Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-range-property-excel) accepts 2 cells like

```
Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Cells(i, firstPos), Cells(i, firstPos))
```

or one address

```
Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Cells(i, firstPos).Address)
```

but not 1 cells

```
Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Cells(i, firstPos)) 'not valid
```

because therefore you can use `Cells` directly

```
Set rngDest = wksDest.Cells(i, firstPos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Cells(i, firstPos))` to:

```
Set rngDest = wksDest.Cells(i, firstPos)
```